# How to handle "not label Y" in a multi class machine learning problem?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a train data set that comprises information in the form:

```
  feature 1, ..., feature N, label
1 x1,        ..., xn,        A
2 x1,        ..., xn,        B
3 x1,        ..., xn,        C
  ...
4 x1,        ..., xn,        not A
5 x1,        ..., xn,        not B
  ...
```

In the test dataset, the labels A, B, C should be predicted.

I would like to use the information in row 4 and 5 in order to avoid overfitting.

Which sklearn classes / tools can I use to utilize the "not A" and "not B" information in rows like 4 and 5?

Comment: Can you replace `not A` with `[B, C]`? Also, if you have one label per instance and not a list of labels this is not multilabel problem, but multiclass problem.

Comment: Thanks :-) Regarding 1: I understand your question in the way if I could reform the problem to deliver a prediction `[B, C}`? - No, this is not possible (or did you mean that one could rephrase the problem programmatically in that way? => maybe? I am not sure. But how would I continue afterwards?). Regarding 2: yes, you are right. It is a multiclass problem. I corrected the tile accordingly.

Comment: I meant logically, does `not A` imply `[B, C]` or there are other possible categories?

Comment: There are other categories possible, yes